# Is it a problem to always have water around the tub flange?

Tags: plumbing-fixture

Is it a problem to have water around a new bath tub drain flange?

Only, does it dry up after an hour later from consent sponging.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Can you clarify a bit please... You're saying that when you're done with a bath/shower, some water sits in the recess between the tub and the drain flange? Also, you're saying that it doesn't evaporate on its own after an hour or two, but that you have to sponge it up to get it to dry? Please [edit] these details into your post, and maybe include a picture of the flange when dry and another when wet - these will help people to better see how the flange is installed to get a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: The drain flange should not be sitting higher than the tub bottom.   Was this recently installed?

Comment: Agreed, @Kris. However, our drain is installed properly but there's always a small ring of water between the tub and flange. It does dry out after a while, though, despite the high humidity here in the summer. That's why I was hoping the OP would post some pics so we can _see_ what's going on. A picture is worth 1000 words, and all... ;)

Comment: @FreeMan - you need to read my answer.  Time to go shopping and read reviews to get rid of that ring!

Comment: This question is also why I hate buying a tub that doesn't include a trim kit or at least recommendations.   Every tub has a slightly different cutout - some way different.   There is not one "ultimate" flange that works for everything.   You get something too small then you have a tiny bit of water around the outside.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't ideal.   And it isn't something that anyone strives for.   However it isn't the end of the world.   What it means is that you will have to wipe it with a bleach product every 3-4 weeks as pink mold will grow.

Having the flange sit at a slight angle with no lip outside is what you want.   There should only be droplets left, not a few tablespoons sitting, unable to get over the flange ledge.

[image]

Take the image above.

1. The flange on the drain has a bad slope.   This makes things easier for the stopper but causes water to pool.
2. Even if the slope were better the outer body of the drain flange looks too big for this molded opening.   So even if it sloped down better there would still be water on the outer ring... albeit far less than the picture shows.

**So what can you do?**

You are going to have to replace the tub drain (or sometimes referred to tub flange).   These screw off with a bit of muscle and only takes a few minutes to replace.   In the end this will come down to a shopping question because to fix your tub you need to find the right size and slant from your tub drain flange.   There will be 1000s of choices for your size tub.   You have to find one based on the outside flange diameter, tilt, and whether you need a stopper or not.

Then you need to install it flat using plumbers putty, so your install doesn't cause a ridge.